# Rails 5: how to change log level in rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 5.2.5 and I want to change the log level when I use rails console.
I want to stress that I don't want to change any file in the project, but just to do the change from the console.

I saw some suggestions to run:

```
conf.log_level = :debug
```

in the console, but I got the error

> NameError (undefined local variable or method `config' for
> main:Object) Did you mean?  conf

I also tried to execute

```
conf.log_level = :debug
```

but I also got the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> 2: from (irb):11
> 1: from (irb):11:in `rescue in irb_binding'

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `YourApp` configuration (`YourApp`located at `config/environment/[environment].rb`

```rb
YourApp.configure do
 config.log_level = :info
end
```

Or you can use `Rails.application.configure`

```
2.5.8 :005 > Rails.application.configure do
2.5.8 :006 >     puts(config.log_level)
2.5.8 :007?>   end
debug
 => nil
2.5.8 :008 > Rails.application.configure do
2.5.8 :009 >     config.log_level = :info
2.5.8 :010?>   end
 => :info
2.5.8 :011 > Rails.application.configure do
2.5.8 :012 >     puts(config.log_level)
2.5.8 :013?>   end
info
```

Comment: "Rails.application.configure do" worked for me